# What is the retention period for GitHub Pages created with GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I am trying to write a GitHub Actions workflow that will generate a code coverage report and some documentation, save them as artifacts, and later upload them to my github.io page.

Here is a shortened version of my workflow file:

```
name: compileAndRunTests

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow one concurrent deployment
concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  buildEverything:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Checkout repository"
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      ... download prerequisited ...
      ... build project ...
      - name: "Save coverage report artifact"
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with: 
          name: code-coverage-report
          path: build/ccov
          retention-days: 1
      - name: "Save documentation artifact"
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with: 
          name: doxygen-docs
          path: docs
          retention-days: 1

  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [buildEverything]
    steps:
      - name: "Checkout repository"
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: "Download code coverage report artifact"
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: code-coverage-report
          path: gh_pages
      - name: "Download documentation artifact"
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: doxygen-docs
          path: gh_pages
      - name: "Setup Pages"
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v2
      - name: "Upload pages artifact"
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
        with:
          path: gh_pages
      - name: "Deploy to GitHub Pages"
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v1
```

There is an `index.html` inside gh_pages folder that just links to the HTML pages created in the artifacts

If I specify retention period for artifacts to 1 day, will that in any way impact the content displayed on the GitHub pages site?

Comment: If it just links to the artifacts, and the artifacts go away, what do you _expect_ will happen?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The confusion comes from the fact that the actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1 creates a gh_pages artifact with no specified retention period, which contains all the data from the other artifacts needed to display everything, and as far as I can tell, what I am writing is similar to normal github pages publishing that does rely only on artifacts, and those github pages do not really expire

Comment: @TheMemeMachine I think it's default to [one day](https://github.com/actions/upload-pages-artifact/blob/main/action.yml#L13-L16)